# Emails are stuck in drafts sent through office.js API in Outlook for Mac

Tags: exchangewebservices, office-js

I am using office api to create drafts and send the email. Once the email is sent, it is being delivered and I see the email in sent folder. But I see the same email in drafts folder too. I need to go and manually delete the email from drafts folder or if I quit Outlook and reopen, the email is removed from drafts folder. I believe this to be a caching issue in Outlook for Mac. Please help

Here are he api's I am using to save draft and send email.
`Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync()`
`Office.context.mailbox.makeEwsRequestAsync()`

Here is he SOAP payload I am using to send email

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
  xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
  <soap:Header>
    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />
  </soap:Header>
  <soap:Body>
    <SendItem xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
        SaveItemToFolder="true">
      <ItemIds>
        <t:ItemId Id="${itemData.id}" ChangeKey="${itemData.changeKey}" />
      </ItemIds>
      <SavedItemFolderId>
        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="sentitems" />
      </SavedItemFolderId>
    </SendItem>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>;
```

Comment: Can you share the soap payload, which you use with makeEwsRequestAsync ?

Comment: Added SOAP payload to he question. Thanks for looking into it.